# how to resize an absolute image that is scale to the window size

Tags: jquery, css, image

Is there a way to resize an absolute image that is scale to the window when the outer image start scaling?

this is what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/q4gv5oah/

I want the content img scale down when the bgimage start resizing down when the window size is small.
and keep the content img always in the middle of the bgimage.
(best is just to enough to cover the 650X150 (X) in this example)

I am thinking I need to add left and right margin to the content image, so when the screen is small, the margin will push the image smaller, but it doesn't seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bgimage">
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/650x150" />
    </div>

  <div class="content">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}

.bgimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bgimage img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    max-width: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content>img {
    max-width: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand very well what you want, could you reexplain?

Comment: I just want the .content img always in that middle spot. when like the screen width is 500px, it will be 100px for that img. but when the screen is like 400px, i want that img width to be 80px

Comment: the px above is just an example, I want it to be in percentage scale.

Comment: You want the smaller picture to stay at the bottom and in the centre. Is there a particular reason you want it to have `position: absolute`, or is that just the way you are keeping it at the bottom for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img  class="bgimage" src="http://placehold.it/650x150" />
  <img class="smimage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />       
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}

.bgimage {
    width: 100%; 
}

.smimage {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:10%;
    border:1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I want. thanks. sorry for not explain it too well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/q4gv5oah/1/

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  border:1px red solid;
  max-width:50px;
  width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you think about my solution? You wanted:

> I want the content img scale down when the bgimage start resizing down when the window size is small. and keep the content img always in the middle of the bgimage.

So in my solution you have centered big image set as background and centered small image. The bigger image will fit the window because of `background-size:cover;` and centered and smaller will be centered too. It will depend on which size of smaller image you would like to have. Another Example of my solution would be:

"width" of smaller image => 30% so "left" would be 35% because 
35%(left)+35%(right)+30%(image) = 100% of width. I've learned that the best way to fit content is creating relative children to its parent. And other thing that I would suggest would be using this:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

For me it is very useful code. Add it as first css style file and you are always sure that nothing "not expected" will happen.

```css
html,

div,

body {

  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  right: 0;

  top: 0;

}

.bgimage {

  background: url("http://placehold.it/650x150") no-repeat;

  background-size: cover;

  position: relative;

  width: 100%;

  background-position: center;

}

.smimage {

  position: relative;

  margin-left: auto;

  margin-right: auto;

}

.smimage img {

  bottom: 0 !important;

  width: 20%;

  display: block;

  position: absolute;

  border: 1px solid black;

  left: 40%;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bgimage">
    <div class="smimage">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```